# Eclipse and JDK 1.8

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, java-8, efxclipse

I'm quite new to Java, I have installed Eclipse mars and I'm using JDK 1.8.0_65, and also I have installed e(fx)clipse after that I got an error:

"You are not running your eclipse instance with Java8. The JavaFX tooling is disabled because of this.Make Java8 the default system java or adjust your eclipse.ini to pass -vm pointing to your Java8 install. "

How to solve this problem?

[image: Eclipse error]